# Editing an HTML page with Clojure's zip maps and Hickory

Tags: html, clojure

**UPDATE:** See updated observations below.

**ORIGINAL:**

I have a usage question about the Clolure library Hickory. I want to use it to find code listings in an HTML page and do syntax highlighting on those pages. (This is a desktop app, not a web app.) Here is what I have tried.

```clj
(ns ....
  (:require [clojure.data.zip.xml :as zx]
            [clojure.zip :as zip]
            [clygments.core :as cly]
            [hickory.core :as hkc]
            [hickory.render :as hkr]
            [hickory.zip :as hkz])
  ...)

  (defn hilite
  "Return a version of the input HTML with syntax highlighted
  code listings."
  [html-in]
  (let [hz (hkz/hickory-zip (hkc/as-hickory (hkc/parse html-in))) ; Convert to zipmap.
        cz (zx/xml-> hz :html :body :pre :code)]                  ; Get array of zips containing code listings.
    (doseq [code-z cz]                                            ; For each code listing...
      (let [code-n (zip/node code-z)]                             ; Convert to a zipmap to node.
        (if-let [lang (get-in code-n [:attrs :class])]            ; See if the node contains a class...
          (when (.startsWith lang "language-")                    ; ...with a language declaration.
            (let [language (str/replace lang "language-" "")      ; Extract the language.
                  cntnt (:content code-n)                         ; Get the content (the code listing).
                  hili (cly/highlight cntnt (keyword language) :html {:styles "xcode"}) ; Do the highlighting.
                  prsed (first (hkc/parse-fragment hili))]        ; Parse the highlighted code listing.
              (zip/replace code-z prsed)                          ; Replace the original with the highighted version.
              (zip/root code-z))))))                              ; Unzip and apply the changes.
    (hkr/hickory-to-html (zip/node hz))))                         ; Return the html with highlighted code listings.
```

Things work fine up to the point where I try to replace the existing code listing with the highlighted version -- the code listings are found correctly and highlighted versions are generated correctly. But I just get back a copy of the original HTML, not the highlighted version. I assume I am getting something wrong with `zip/replace` and `zip/root`, but I don't know what. I have been looking at the docs and examples for `hickory` and `clojure.zip`, but still haven't gotten to a working version.

Do you see what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**: As was pointed out by Alan Thompson, replacing the contents of a node does not do the edit in-place but returns a copy with the modification, as is typical for Clojure. But there was still more wrong. The update itself was structured incorrectly. The structure of the new node intended to replace the existing node has to be fleshed out a bit more. Here is a revised version that sort of works.

```clj
(defn hilite
  "Return a version of the input HTML with syntax highlighted
  code listings."
  [html-in]
  (let [hz (hkz/hickory-zip (hkc/as-hickory (hkc/parse html-in))) ; Convert to zipmap.
        cz (zx/xml-> hz :html :body :pre :code)]                  ; Get array of zips containing code listings.
    (doseq [code-z cz]                                            ; For each code listing...
      (let [code-n (zip/node code-z)]                             ; Convert to a zipmap to node.
        (if-let [lang (get-in code-n [:attrs :class])]            ; See if the node contains a class...
          (when (.startsWith lang "language-")                    ; ...with a language declaration.
            (let [language (str/replace lang "language-" "")      ; Extract the language.
                  cntnt (:content code-n)                         ; Get the content (the code listing).
                  hili (cly/highlight cntnt (keyword language) :html {:styles "xcode"}) ; Do the highlighting.
                  hck-hili (hkc/as-hickory (first (hkc/parse-fragment hili)))       ; NEW
                  new-node {:type :element :attrs {:class (str "lang-" language)}   ; NEW
                            :tag :code :content [hck-hili]}                         ; NEW
                  nz (zip/root (zip/replace code-z new-node))]    ; Unzip and apply the changes. NEW
              (hkr/hickory-to-html nz))))))))                     ; Generate the html with highlighted code listings.
```

By the time the HTML is generated at the bottom of the function, it contains the highlighted code listing. There are still a few problems with this though. First, since this editing takes place in a `doseq` form, it returns `nil`, not the generated HTML. Second, if there is more than one listing to highlight, each pass through the `doseq` is editing the original HTML, not one that contains any previous edits. Sigh. Have to re-think the approach.

Answer (score 2):

Not being familiar with Hickory, it looks like these 2 lines are the problem:

```
(zip/replace code-z prsed) 
(zip/root code-z)
```

The return value of `replace` is not being used, so `root` is being called with the original value of `code-z`.  You probably meant for something more like this:

```
(zip/root 
  (zip/replace code-z prsed))
```

so that `root` is begin called with the *output* of `replace` as its input. Since data structures in Clojure are immutable, any changes generate a new data structure as the *return value* of the function; the original *input* to the function remains unchanged.

Comment: You are, of course, correct. I thought this felt a bit "magical" -- somehow getting in place edits on an immutable data structure. I was also not forming the replacement node correctly. I'll update the question with that fix later.

Comment: Also, since these are not in-place edits, the fundamental approach of the function will not work. When there are multiple code listings, each one will generate a modified version of the original html. No single version will have all of the code listings highlighted. More thought needed about the structure of the function.

Answer (score 0):

After some additional research, I came across [this blog post](https://ravi.pckl.me/short/functional-xml-editing-using-zippers-in-clojure/). The solution proposed involves parsing the html into a zipmap and walking the entire tree of nodes. Each node is checked for whether it should be edited, and if so an editing function is applied and used to replace the original node in the tree.

The tree editing is quite general. You give the tree editing function the root node of the zipmap, a predicate that determines if a particular node should be edited, and an editing function that returns a revised version of the node. Here is what I came up with for syntax highlighting code listings in an HTML page.

```
(ns ...
  (:require [clojure.string :as str]
            [clojure.zip :as zip]
            [clygments.core :as cly]
            [hickory.core :as hkc]
            [hickory.render :as hkr]
            [hickory.zip :as hkz]))

(defn is-highlightable?
  "Return true if the node is of a type that this program can
  highlight. Specifically, is the node wrapped in a :pre tag,
  tagged as :code and does it include a language name."
  [node]
  (let [is-pre (= (:tag node) :pre)
        fc (first (:content node))  ; Get inside the <pre> tag.
        has-code (= (:tag fc) :code)
        has-class (get-in fc [:attrs :class])
        has-language (when has-class
                       (.startsWith has-class "language-"))]
    (and is-pre has-code has-class has-language)))

    (defn hilight-node
      "Return a highlighted version of the source code in the node."
      [node]
      (let [fc (first (:content node))        ; Get inside the <pre> tag.
            lang (get-in fc [:attrs :class])
            language (str/replace lang "language-" "")
            cntnt (first (:content fc))
            hili (cly/highlight cntnt (keyword language) :html)
            frag (hkc/parse-fragment hili)
            hck-hili (hkc/as-hickory (first frag))
            new-node {:type :element :attrs {:class (str "lang-" language)}
                      :tag  :div :content [hck-hili]}]
        new-node))

      (defn edit-html-tree
        "Take a zipper, a function that matches a pattern in the tree,
         and a function that edits the current location in the tree.  Examine the tree
         nodes in depth-first order, determine whether the matcher matches, and if so
         apply the editor."
        [zipper matcher editor]
        (loop [loc zipper]
          (if (zip/end? loc)
            (zip/root loc)
            (if-let [matched (matcher (zip/node loc))]
              (let [new-loc (zip/edit loc editor)]
                (if (not= (zip/node new-loc) (zip/node loc))
                  (recur (zip/next new-loc))))
              (recur (zip/next loc))))))

      (defn hilight-syntax
        "Return a version of the input HTML where the code listings have
        been syntax highlighted."
        [html-in]
        (hkr/hickory-to-html (edit-html-tree
                               (hkz/hickory-zip (hkc/as-hickory (hkc/parse html-in)))
                               is-highlightable?
                               hilight-node)))
```

The code is specific to the way my input HTML is laid out to begin with, but could probably be used with few modifications. The `edit-tree` function is quite general, as mentioned above, and can be used for other, similar editing tasks just by supplying a different matching predicate and node editing function.